# Unclear behavior DOS application's function

Tags: dos, reverse-engineering, pascal, ida, disassembly

I'm trying to reverse some DOS application. It's uses *.VAR file like database (perhaps encoding this file). That's application looks like system for testing students. The application shows random questions from the DB-file and get your answer.
In this place programm read VAR-file length, then open the file and assign it to "newFilePtr_256_byte" var (yes, it's lenght 256 byte).
Next, going call of SUBJ FUNCTION (first screenshot).
After there is FileCounter check and do this call again (until all file would be read).

[image: How the function is being called]

The function, i can't explain for, on second screenshot.
It's read a symbol from newFilePtr_256_byte and write it to console (nothing on console in real life working)?
Or it's do something else?

I can't recognize function behavior, coz i don't know, where i can get fully description Pascal functions in assembler listing.

[image: How the function looks like]

I don't put in my question listing of caller function, coz it's really big.

Comment: Are you sure that `Read_Text_Char_` is `Read(var f; ...)` and `Write_Text_` is `Write(var f:...)`? Perhaps these functions are part of [this library](https://books.google.com/books?id=5gBfrN_v7RQC&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=pascal+%22write_text%22&source=bl&ots=0uqO2yKRTJ&sig=IRt2i4WYoGpdLpGLkxHxMQfLMS8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7wH7VI_2JoKINoClgbgB&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pascal%20%22write_text%22&f=false).

Comment: It's IDA's comments. And perhaps you're right!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can recognize, this function encode file content, by xoring with 0CDh constant, and then write it to buffer in memory.